# Webpack Typescript errors on fresh Nestjs app

Tags: typescript, webpack, nestjs

After generating a new project with `nest new [project name]`, selecting my package manager and executing `yarn start` or `npm start` my project throws the following errors:

```
$ nest start
node_modules/@types/tapable/index.d.ts:7:15 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './node_modules/tapable' or its corresponding type declarations.

7 export * from './node_modules/tapable';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:32:3 - error TS2305: Module '"tapable"' has no exported member 'Tapable'.

32   Tapable,
     ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1062:23 - error TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

1062             resolver: SyncWaterfallHook;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1063:22 - error TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

1063             factory: SyncWaterfallHook;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1064:28 - error TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

1064             beforeResolve: AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook;
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1065:27 - error TS2707: Generic type 'AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

1065             afterResolve: AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook;
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1066:27 - error TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

1066             createModule: SyncBailHook;
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1067:21 - error TS2707: Generic type 'SyncWaterfallHook<T, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 1 and 2 type arguments.

1067             module: SyncWaterfallHook;
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1068:27 - error TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

1068             createParser: HookMap;
                               ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1070:30 - error TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

1070             createGenerator: HookMap;
                                  ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1071:24 - error TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

1071             generator: HookMap;
                            ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1080:33 - error TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

1080                 evaluateTypeof: HookMap;
                                     ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1081:27 - error TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

1081                 evaluate: HookMap;
                               ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1082:37 - error TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

1082                 evaluateIdentifier: HookMap;
                                         ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1083:44 - error TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

1083                 evaluateDefinedIdentifier: HookMap;
                                                ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1084:47 - error TS2314: Generic type 'HookMap<H>' requires 1 type argument(s).

1084                 evaluateCallExpressionMember: HookMap;
                                                   ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:1085:28 - error TS2707: Generic type 'SyncBailHook<T, R, AdditionalOptions>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.

1085                 statement: SyncBailHook;
```

I already tried reinstalling the nest cli, stried switching between npm and yarn, removing the dist folder and removing the node_modules folder (and installing the dependencies)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you could ignore this using `"skipLibCheck": true` in your `tsconfig.json` under `"compilerOptions"` tho

EDIT
looks like they [fix that in `@nestjs/cli@7.6.0`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/6764#issuecomment-808056980)

Answer (score 10):

Upgrading Nest's CLI and re-installing modules, should fix it

`npm install -g @nestjs/cli@latest`

`rm -rf node_modules`

`rm package-lock.json`

`npm install`

Comment: In most cases it is not a good idea to remove `package-lock.json`.

Comment: @IvanP in most cases it is a good idea to remove `package-lock.json` and never track it again.